# Add event to a specific marker using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML 5 video player which I have added timeline markers.

I would like to add an event into a specific marker eg on click to play another video or show another div or text,

Here is what I have so far

```
 var video = videojs('video1');
    //load markers
    video.markers({

        markers: [{
                time: 7,
                class: "first_step_circle"
            },
            {
                time: 16,
                text: "is",
                class: "second_step_circle"
            },
            {
                time: 23.6,
                text: "so"
            },
            {
                time: 28,
                text: "cool"
            }
        ]
    });

 $('.second_step_circle').on('click', function(){
        openPopUp('.persona2PopUp');
        console.log(openPopUp('.persona2PopUp'))
    })
```

Here is div I want to show to my video player

```
<div class="lightbox persona2PopUp">
    <img src="images/Matt.jpg">
    <h5>Matt Briscoe</h5>
    <p>Role: Developer</p>
    <p>Bio: Matt has been a manager for 4 years. This alkjdlas asldkjasldj aslkdj aklsdjlsakdjalskjd salkdj salkjd</p>
    <p>Previous Experiences</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
        <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
        <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I check class with name `second_step_circle` in DOM it's available, but when I click nothing is happening , here is docs for videojs marker [videojs marker](http://sampingchuang.com/videojs-markers) .

what do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: Two ways I think you can use .. 1st: with `onMarkerClick` the plugin built in function .. 2nd: to use `$(document).on('click' , '.second_step_circle', function(){
`